# Redirect dns on a network

Tags: dns

I don't know enough to even ask my question, but here is my situation:At my university, when I type weather into a url bar, my browser will offer to take me to the website "weather". When I get to this page, it just says the words, "ITS GOOD" and nothing else. In the url bar there is nothing but weather. i can ping "weather" in command prompt, and the redirect is to "weather.metr.xxxxxx.edu" with a full response. What is happening here, and how could I find other such dns redirects on this network?

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect a dns in your /etc/hosts file on a unix or a mac machine. If you do vi /etc/hosts, it would open up the file.
Add 

`weather.metr.xxxxxx.edu weather`

save and close the file. After wards if you do ping weather it would do what are describing above.

There might be something fancier going in the university network but this is the basic idea.